# Google Cloud Windows Server - Unable to launch a Command prompt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012-r2

When attempting to forcely uninstall a software from the server, I switched off these two components from MSCONFIG.EXE:

[MSConfig Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxBeY.png)

After rebooting the server, it doesn't respond anymore to RDP connections.

The Google Cloud Panel shows that the server is running, has an internal and external IP Address, but I cannot access it by any means. I already rebooted, stopped and started it many times.

This is the output for SERIAL PORT #1:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20181112_143635-google)
Total RAM Size = 0x00000000f0000000 = 3840 MiB
CPUs found: 1     Max CPUs supported: 1
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=104857600 = 51200 MiB
drive 0x000f2a30: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=104857600
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
```

I am able to connect to SERIAL PORT #2, to try a deeper troubleshooting, but the first message after connection is this:

```
Computer is booting, SAC started and initialized
```

And when trying to open CMD command, this is the response:

```
SAC>cmd
Error: Unable to launch a Command Prompt.  The service responsible for launching
Command Prompt channels has not yet registered.  This may be because the
service is not yet started, is disabled by the administrator, is
malfunctioning or is unresponsive.
```

Does anyone know how to recover this server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You unselected "Load system services". This means that nothing is loaded in Windows. The services that are required so that you can access the system remotely are not running.

You have two options:

1. Mount the disk on another Windows system, mount the registry and change the settings for these two items (I don't rember but this information is on the Internet). Then unmount the registry and create another VM with the disk.
2. Create a new instance and attach this disk as the second disk drive. Copy all the data from the second drive to the first drive. You will loose system settings, applications, etc but at least you can save your data.

Comment: That worked! I attached the disk in another instance, copied all files I needed and recreated everything with these files. Thanks!